# VSTO insert image into word, excel, power-point and mail attachment in outlook

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

I'm developing VSTO application. At some point i create an image that i want to display it to the user.
My question:

1. How to insert that image into the word document.
2. How to insert that image into the **active** excel sheet.
3. How to insert that image into a new slide in Power-Point.
4. How to insert that image as attachment in mail in outlook.

**Update:** what i have tried

for word `WordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(fileFullPath, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);` and it's working.

for excel i got `HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Error`

Comment: come on... you know StackOverflow rules... what have you tried? :]

Comment: can someone at least help me in outlook ?

Answer (score 2):

I have found two solutions to this question:

First:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagesurl);
```

Second:

```
   Slide activeSlide = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide;
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape ppPicture =
   activeSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(imageurl ,
   MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, 0, 0);
   ppPicture.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = imageurl 
 }
```